# Эффект подпрыгивания при достижении начала или конца списка RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Имеется `RecyclerView`. Проблема заключается в том, что обычно при достижении начала или конца списка имеется эффект, как будто список по инерции движется дальше буквально на пару миллиметров и сразу же становится на место. Как будто подпрыгивает. Этот эффект стандартный, длится меньше секунды и он имеется везде, где есть хоть какая-то прокрутка экрана. Однако он отсутствует у меня в этих `RecyclerView`. Прошу помочь в решении этой проблемы.

**UPD:**

**1.** Ссылка на [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LUmEvxpXdw), где можно заметить этот эффект внизу. Обращаю внимание, что речь идёт не об эффекте `overScrollMode`.

**2.** Важное дополнение, что эффект появляется если список не доводить пальцем до конца, а как бы подтолкнуть его, чтобы он двигался по инерции и дойдя до конца (или начала), появится этот эффект подпрыгивания или отпружинивания списка ))

Comment: Возможно, вам подойдёт сторонняя либа для этого: https://github.com/EverythingMe/overscroll-decor

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо за предложенный вариант. Но хотелось бы без сторонних библиотек. Ведь это вполне стандартное поведение...

Comment: Это стандарт на айфонах. В Андроиде только сторонними средствами можно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, именно стандарт без использования сторонних библиотек это имеется на Андроиде при прокрутке чего-либо. Я нигде для этого эффекта библиотеку не использовал, но он есть везде (кроме RecyclerView). Он происходит очень-очень быстро. Я раньше его даже не замечал до тех пор, пока не увидел его отсутствие. Разница сразу заметна. Просто я не знаю название этому эффекту. Если получится записать видео, то я попробую показать этот момент, хоть он и длится меньше секунды.

Comment: Может у вас какой нибудь Xiaomi с их MiUI или Meizu, на которых это может быть стандартом. В чистом андроиде никакого эффекта подпрыгивания нет, а значит получить его стандартными средствами не получится. Вам это уже третий человек говорит.

Comment: @eugeneek, если третий человек, это ведь не значит что это так. Я этот эффект видел даже на эмуляторах. Он присутствует даже во всех туториалах на ютубе когда идёт пролистывание, т.е. хоть какой-нибудь скроллинг. Он настолько не заметен, что на него может даже не обращают внимание.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ещё дополню, что этот эффект появляется если не просто довести список до конца пальцем, а именно отпустить его, чтобы он двигался по инерции и тогда этот эффект возникнет при достижении конца списка (или начала).

Comment: Дайте ссылку на видео тогда, где это видно. Аж интересно стало.

Comment: @eugeneek, я дополнил свой вопрос ссылкой на видео и условием, при котором заметен этот эффект. Очень надеюсь, что поймёте о чём речь.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, посмотрите, пожалуйста, дополнение к моему вопросу. Там видео, чтобы можно было понять о чём речь. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: @Gamlet Это стандартный эффект для `ListView`. В `RecyclerView` от него, видимо, отказались.

Comment: @eugeneek, это стандартный эффект для всего, что скролится. Могу ошибаться, но очень мало вероятно, что отказались от него именно в `RecyclerView`. На днях попробую реализовать `RecyclerView` вне фрагментов, возможно в этом причина.

Comment: Как скажете. Удачи вам. Только правильнее было бы сначала попробовать и уже потом задавать вопрос.

Comment: Привет! Я понимаю, про что ты говоришь и тоже хочу реализовать эффект подпрыгивания у себя. Ты разобрался как это сделать? Я до сих пор нет :)

Comment: @YaPV, к сожалению пока что нет ))

Answer (score 5):

Вы наверное что-то путаете - в стандартном Андроиде нет эффекта "подпрыгивания" (*bounce effect*), там есть понятие *overscroll*, когда вы доходите до начала/конца списка сверху/снизу появляется такая полосочка (*overscroll edge effect*):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оверскролл можно немножко контролировать, за это отвечает атрибут `RecyclerView/ScrollView` - `android:overScrollMode="always/never"` с разными флагами

Если уж прямо хотите *bounce effect*, то здесь только к сторонним либам, ну или писать самому анимацию.

Отличная либа [вот эта](https://github.com/chthai64/overscroll-bouncy-android)
- встраиваете в лейаут, что то типа:

```
<com.chauthai.overscroll.RecyclerViewBouncy
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: К сожалению речь идёт не о `overScrollMode`, это именно такой эффект, название которого я не знаю. Но по виду очень похож на ваш пример из ссылки, только он происходит очень-очень быстро. Я раньше его даже не замечал до тех пор, пока не увидел его отсутствие. Он есть, и это именно стандартное поведение при прокрутке чего-либо.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, дополнение к моему вопросу. Я там скинул ссылку на видео. Возможно так будет понятнее о чём именно идёт речь.

Comment: Не видел такого эффекта на Андроиде - ну вот честно... Вы говорите видимо об эффекте, который был реализован на какой то спец. прошивке или оболочке. В стандарте нет такого...

Comment: Ладно я могу ошибаться, но когда вам говорят уважаемые люди @ЮрийСПб и eugeneek хором - я бы призадумался